# Docker - Add Python and Dependencies to Apache

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a python script that I am trying to create a `docker` container for. I am new to `docker` so please excuse if this is real simple!

If I am setting up my existing `python` script on a new system I always run the following to install dependencies....

```
pip install numpy opencv-python dlib imutils
```

I have a basic `Dockerfile` that loads `PHP` with `apache` like this...

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Is there a way I can add `Python` into the stack and install those dependencies? Or have I got Docker totally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly on very first point, you need to get some packages from Python then try following once(as an example, I am importing Python's 2.7 version's image here).

```
FROM python2.7-slim
```

Then for multiple packages installations you could create a file named `requirements.txt`(which will have all packages details in it) and then could run following command too in it.

```
cat requirements.txt
numpy
opencv-python
dlib
imutils

pip install -r requirements.txt
```

---

---

> If I am setting up my existing python script on a new system I always
>   run the following to install dependencies....

***Little explanation on Concept of Docker:*** So concept of Docker is NOT TO INSTALL dependencies on any machines and make our codes to run on any machine without putting additional stuff to install our code's dependencies etc. Basically our Dockerize solution should be capable to handle any system. Here is what the steps would be:

1- Create your code in Python(here taking example of it).
2- Now place it in docker's directory.
3- MOST important step create a file named `Dockerfile` in docker's directory.
4- Now mention all sequence of commands in it, following is an example of Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python2.7-slim
DIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python","your_python_code_file"]
```

So here you could see whenever we build our image(combination of our code and Dockerfile) we need NOT TO install anything in our actual server/machine this is benefit of Docker  our image SHOULD BE dependency free. Once we build our image and post it to repository same image could be used by any other person on any other machine too.

Comment: If I try like that then I get dockerfile parse error, FROM requires either one or three argumanets

Comment: This creates a just-Python image.  I'm not sure about the relationship between the PHP wrapper in the original question and the Python script; if there's something like a Flask server that the PHP can call out to then this is a good start for a 2-container Docker Compose setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze, why I had taken `python`'s example here because OP needs to install certain packages in it using pip.